# Pyramiding Entrys - Need SL/TP for each Trade

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to be able to take more trades in a row. I can enter this under Pyramiding. For example 5.

Then it also works with the entrances. But the SL and TP are adjusted with every new trade.

How do I adjust the code so that the SL/TP for each trade remains as it was at the entry point?

```
    SL = input.float(8, step=0.1, minval=0, title='SL', group=' StopLoss/TakeProfit')
    TP = input.float(0.65, step=0.01, minval=0, title='TP', group=' StopLoss/TakeProfit')

    stopLoss = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - SL/100)

    takeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + TP/100) 

    if wt_buySignal and ema_folge_long and close > ema1    
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

    strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
```

```
///// Tests what i try but also not work

// if wt_buySignal and ema_folge_long and close > ema1
//     stopLoss = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - SL/100)
//     takeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + TP/100) 

//     // entryId = "Long" + str.tostring(bar_index)
//     strategy.entry("Long" + str.tostring(bar_index), strategy.long)

//     strategy.exit("Exit", "Long" + str.tostring(bar_index), stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)

//     // strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", from_entry=entryId, stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
```